# adding item to a list within an instance of a class

Tags: python, function, class, append, instance

I have a class with four lists. I intend to create several instances of this class. If I understand correctly, each instance should have its own lists. I wrote a function to add to the list, but I am struggling to make it work. I do need to use `input ()`.with the following code I get the message: type error. line 12. add_item_list_one() missing one required positional argument : self

```
class My_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_one = []
        self.list_two = []
        self.list_three = []
        self.list_four = []

    def add_item_list_one(self):
        self.list_one.append(int(input()))

obj_one = My_class
obj_one.add_item_list_one()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just assign `My_class` to `obj_one`, but do not instanciate it. Add parentheses after `My_class` to assign an instance of your `My_class` to `obj_one`:

```
obj_one = My_class()
obj_one.add_item_list_one()
```

Comment: I am glad I could help you :) Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: I intend to. it won't let me mark it until I wait another 5 min.